# How to encode a string using excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to encode a string with the rule below:

If I have a string like `ABCDEAC`, I want to encode it like `1234513`.
For a string like `CDABAEB`. I want to encode it like "1234354"

The rule to encode is: With the first character of string always assigned 1 and will increase gradually by position.

Can an Excel formula (no VBA) be used to resolve it?

Many thanks for considering my request.

Nothing. I am just thinking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are an user of ***Microsoft-365*** then could use-

```
=LET(
x,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),
y,UNIQUE(x),
CONCAT(XLOOKUP(x,y,SEQUENCE(ROWS(y))))
)
```

We can simplify the formula using `XMATCH()` instead of `XLOOKUP()`.

```
=LET(
x,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),
y,UNIQUE(x),
CONCAT(XMATCH(x,y))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. I guess you could replace `XLOOKUP(x,y,SEQUENCE(ROWS(y)))` with simply `XMATCH(x,y)` as well.

Comment: @JosWoolley Nice suggestion. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thankiu so much <3